# Xcode how to create new objects relative to the last one? (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, loops, uiimageview

Ok I have a general concept of how to achieve this in swift but I am still a little puzzled.

So I want to be able to create new objects programmatically (like a new UIimageview) but have them spaced relative to the last one. I don't want all the images ontop of each other so how does one retrieve the index of the latest object created?

Ex. For example if I wanted 20 'apple' objects side by side it would not be practical to individually place them on a storyboard but to create them through code in the correct position.

Comment: please paste code and add images, explain so we help.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create 20 objects related to last object. What you mean by related. I assume with your `20 Apple` example you want to display them in a view in an ordered list.

If this is the case then you can use a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` and display each image by adding them as a subview in `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell`.

Let me know this solution works for you. If not please provide more details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `frame` property to manipulate the location of your `UIImageView`.

Create new variable to store x or y location before `UIImageView` creation and set its x or y frame to those variable.

Then just add the height and space to those variable before you use it to create new `UIImageView`.

```
var yPos:CGFloat = 20.0

let image1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: yPos, width: 75, height: 50))

yPos += image1.frame.size.height + 10.0

let image2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: yPos, width: 75, height: 50))

//repeat for more UIImageView
//or using for loop code for more elegant code

for i in 0...5
{
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: yPos, width: 75, height: 50))

    imageView.tag = i

    yPos += imageView.frame.size.height + 10.0
    containerView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers, I used seto nugroho's idea. Here is my code

```
var numApples = 20    //The amount of objects being created in this case it is apples

var apple: UIImageView?   //Declare the UIImageView 

var xPos:CGFloat = 20.0 


for i in 0...numApples 
{
        var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "apple")!
        apple = UIImageView(image: image)
        apple!.frame = CGRectMake(xPos,50,40,50)
        xPos += apple!.frame.size.width + 10.0 
        apple!.tag = i
        self.view.addSubview(apple!)
}
```

So I was somewhat vague but what this code simply does is create 20 objects (apples in this case) programmatically and spaces them apart equally and attaches a new tag to each so I know the order in which they were created.